# Why can't I connect to a Postgres database?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I've installed and started a Postgres 9.1 instance on a DigitalOcean droplet.

When I try to connect to it using my PgAdmin III client (settings see below), I get the message that the server is not listening at the specified port.

[image: Connection settings]

The output `netstat -na` at the server side contains a line, which indicates that the server is actually listening on port 5432.

[image: netstat]

Why can't I connect to that server?

Comment: You should post your problem in [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: And trying to answer: Perhaps FireWall blocking ? Did you try to connect to server using its ip adresse ?

Comment: @Houari: it's off-topic for serverfault per the first sentence at http://serverfault.com/about . For a professional admin, it's blazingly obvious that this server doesn't listen to **remote** connections on PG port, thus this question falls right within their "_must demonstrate a minimal understanding"_ close reason.

Comment: How do you solve it? I'm dealing with the same issue.

Comment: @LucasBrito I forgot it, sorry. Either I solved the problem with PostgresQL, or I switched to a different database.

Answer (score 2):

You have probably configured following two files
pg_hba.conf
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
postgresql.conf
listen_addresses='*'

You have to check if the port 5432 is open: http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

Linux:
If it's not then add a rule to your iptables:
iptables -A INPUT -s 0/0 -p tcp --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT

0/0: If you want anybody to access it. 
You can change it to a specific ip address or range of ip addresses

Windows: Configure firewall

Answer (score 0):

You're only listening on localhost (127.0.0.1), so only connections from the same machine will be accepted. Tell Postgres to listen on 0.0.0.0, or, for more security, look into SSH tunnels.

Comment: Specifically you want `listen_addresses=*` in `postgresql.conf` unless you prefer the SSH tunnel.

Comment: @Robin Allen Thanks. Where can I read about how to configure SSH tunnels?

Comment: Looks like you're on Windows so I'd use PuTTY. Look for "Tunnels" in the PuTTY manual, or in the config UI it's in Connection > SSH > Tunnels. On Unix you'd use ssh -L 5432:localhost:5432 you@yourserver, then tell pgAdmin to connect to localhost:5432

Comment: PgAdmin-III supports SSH tunnel setup directly. See the Pgadmin-III manual. Personally I prefer to enable SSL and use direct PostgreSQL connections over SSL though.